# Prove that if $n$ is a positive integer greater than one which is not prime then it is divisible by some prime $p \leq \sqrt{n}$

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

I have just started revising number theory and I am getting stuck on a lot of the "prove that" questions. Any tips and advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1362340/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one method of proving a statement is to negate it and derive a contradiction. so, suppose $n \gt 1$ is a compound integer not divisible by any prime $\le \sqrt{n}$.

then $n$ is divisible by at least two primes, say $p$ and $q$ and each is $\gt \sqrt{n}$

so $n \ge pq \gt \sqrt{n} \sqrt{n}=n$

but a number cannot be strictly larger than itself, which is the required contradiction

Comment: Ah that makes a lot more sense now, thank you David :) !

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $n$ is not prime. Then the decomposition of $n$ is
$$ n = 2^{\alpha_2} 3^{\alpha_3} 5^{\alpha_5} \cdots$$

Take the least $i$ such that $\alpha_i \geqslant 1$ ($i$ is a prime).
Then $n = i\times q$, where $q$ is a positive integer, greater than $i$ because $n$ is not prime.

Suppose $i > \sqrt n$. Then $q > \sqrt n$, and thus $i\times q = n > n$. Contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $n \geq 1$ composite, then write  $n=a\cdot b$, with $1< a,b <n$. By contradiction, suppose that niether  $a$ nor  $b$ is less than $\sqrt{n}$, then  $\dots $

Now, if both $a$ and  $b$ are not prime, you can easily extract a prime satisfying the above property.